# Golang SQL Query Syntax

Tags: go

Getting syntax erro with sql query in golang code. Required proper syntax for this SQL query in golang:

```
rows, errQuery := dbCon.Query("SELECT B.LatestDate
    ,A.SVRName AS ServerName
    ,A.DRIVE
,A.TotalSpace_GB AS TotalSpaceGB
,(ISNULL(A.TotalSpace_GB, 0) - ISNULL(A.FreeSpace_GB, 0)) AS 
 UsedSpaceGB
,A.FreeSpace_GB AS FreeSpaceGB
,CASE 
WHEN ((A.FreeSpace_GB / A.TotalSpace_GB) * 100)  between 25 and 
35
THEN 1
WHEN ((A.FreeSpace_GB / A.TotalSpace_GB) * 100) <= 25   THEN 2
ELSE 0
END AS WARNINGSTATUS
    FROM Table_ServerDiskSpaceDetails A WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN (
SELECT SVRName
,MAX(Dt) LatestDate
FROM Table_ServerDiskSpaceDetails WITH (NOLOCK)
GROUP BY SVRName
) B ON A.Dt = B.LatestDate
AND A.SVRName = B.SVRName
    ORDER BY WARNINGSTATUS DESC
,ServerName
,A.Drive")
```

Comment: What's the syntax error?  Have you tried running the query at console (which usually tells you _where_ the error is)?  What variant of SQL are you running (MySQL, Postgres, etc)?

Comment: It's mssql query working on SQL Management Studio/Console but not working with golang getting a syntax error on this sql query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your SQL statement is on multiple lines, but you're not using the correct multi-line syntax. The correct syntax would be:

```
someLongString := "Line 1 " +    // Don't forget the trailing space
                  "Second line." // This is on the next line.
```

Currently you're just trying to stuff everything between a set of quotes on different lines.

---

EDIT: Per as @Kaedys says below, the following also works and may be more performant.

```
someLongString := `Line 1
                   Second line.`
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can use backticks to annotate a string literal.  New lines are treated properly in such a case.  It also avoids the performance issues that come when concatenating a boatload of strings.

Comment: @Kaedys True, that also preserves all line breaks newlines which is something to be aware of. SQL isn't particularly sensitive to whitespace, but it's good to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

change both your first and last "\"" to "`", or quote your each line of the query string and then add a "+" between each line like

```
"select" +
" *" +
" from" +
" table"
```